# Update UIImageView image inside UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I have a pageViewController with uiImageViews on each view controller (page). The images are downloaded asynchronously. I have no trouble updating the first page before any flipping occurs, but once the pageviewcontroller has been flipped open the currently open page does not update when the image is changed. How can I make the current view controller update its view?

```
-(void) updateImage:(UIImage *) image{
  MyCustomPage * dataViewController = [self.viewControllers lastObject];
  dataViewController.myImageView.image = image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what i needed:

```
MyCustomPage * currentViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:currentPageNum];
NSArray *viewControllers = @[currentViewController];
[self.pageViewCntrl setViewControllers:viewControllers
               direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                animated:NO
              completion:nil];
```

Comment: Your question took 20m u needed to answer it.

Comment: Yes, after a long time of struggling I posted the question only to find the solution shortly thereafter.